# How can I reverse the order of letters/tokens?

Tags: macros, tex-core

I want a simple way to have:

```
\reverseit{abc defg \mycommand}
```

yield

```
\mycommand gfed cba
```

?

(Yes, the original motivation is related to Hebrew and RTL languages, but that can sort of be solved using `\beginR ... \endR`/`\beginL ... \endL` where necessary without changing the language. So I'm asking the general question.)

**Edit:** The solution [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36034/most-efficient-way-to-reverse-a-token-list-tail-recursion) is acceptable as a non-LaTeX-3 solution...

Comment: Related: [Most efficient way to reverse a token list (tail recursion)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36034/most-efficient-way-to-reverse-a-token-list-tail-recursion). Please check if it is a duplicate.

Comment: @MartinScharrer While that question discusses the problem, it was oriented in finding the "most efficient" way. For short token lists the solution I provided (courtesy of the LaTeX3 team) is the shortest.

Comment: Side note the "yield" part isn't equal to the reverse of the original as the space token originally before `\mycommand` is lost.

Comment: Don't understand your comment. There are two space tokens in both sequences.

Comment: Not that it matters, but back then I wanted to say that the tokenization of `\mycommand gfed cba` consist of `\mycommand gfed␣cba` (only one explicit space token) instead of the intended `\mycommand ␣gfed␣cba`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\reverseit { m }
  { \tl_reverse:n { #1 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\reverseit{abc defg \LaTeX}
\end{document}
```

This also honors spaces.

Comment: For completeness, mention `\tl_reverse_items:n`, which does not honor spaces, and puts braces around every item, but is much faster (100 times?). --- Sorry, didn't see that there were spaces in Eyal's example.