# How to make the last word in a sequence the first?

Tags: programming, latex3

I am looking for a macro that would take a string (better to say -- a sequence of words) and output the last word at the fist place before remaning part of the sequence. I want to put this macro into the definition of an environment intended to typeset personal information for a person:

```
\newenvironment{person}[2]%
{% begin definition
    \section*{#2}\label{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}
}{% end definition
\clearpage
}
```

So that instead of

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}
```

there should be

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\reverseit{#2}}
```

The `\reverseit` macro should produce **Alfv\'{e}n Hannes** from **Hannes Alfv\'{e}n** and **Allen James van** from **James van Allen**. It should also handle exceptional case when its argument consist of a single word (eg, **Aristotle**).

**Is is possible to compose such a macro within framework of TeX or, say, using Lua or LaTeX3?**

A receipt proposed as an answert to [How can I reverse the order of letters/tokens?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40225/how-can-i-reverse-the-order-of-letters-tokens) solves my problem only in the case of a sequence which consists of two words.

Comment: Are we to take it that the separator between 'words' here is a space? Do we have to worry about expansion at all?

Comment: @Josepf Wright: the 'words' are separated by spaces, but I am not sure if `Alfv\'{e}n` should be expanded of not.

Comment: I suggest you use some special separator that separates the surname from the first name. Otherwise, you'll get into trouble with Knuth as you wouldn't want _Don Ervin Knuth_ to result in _Knuth Ervin Don._

Answer (score 13):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\protected\def\reverseit#1{\xreverseit{}#1 \relax}
\def\xreverseit#1#2 #3{%
\ifx\relax#3%
#2#1%
\expandafter\xthree
\fi
\xreverseit{#1 #2}#3}
\def\xthree#1#2#3{}
\begin{document}

\reverseit{Hannes Alfv\'{e}n}

\reverseit{}

\reverseit{one}

\reverseit{one two}

\reverseit{one two three}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works for me. Some explanation on how it works would be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, wizards like D.C. don't teach math :) The LaTeX kernel has `\@gobble` (`\@gobbleone`), `\@gobbletwo` and `\@gobblefour`, but left out `\@gobblethree` (=`\xthree`).

Comment: xreverseit collects words seen so far in `#1` and parses up to the next space as `#2` if `#3` is `\relax` that is the end marker inserted at the start so do the reversal outputting `#2` (the last word` followed by `#1` (the preceding words and spaces). Otherwise recursively call the macro, adding the current `#2` into the the words collected so far first argument of `\xreverseit`. The `\xthree` just gobbles the recursive call to terminate the recursion.

Comment: @AhmedMusa it was left out deliberately as we didn't need it and we couldn't afford to waste a csname on an unused macro (latex2e on emtex had less than 100 spare csnames for all user-defined macros and cross references as I recall)

Answer (score 12):

LaTeX3 provides useful tools which hopefully are easier to follow than David's code (examples shamelessly taken from his solution).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3, xparse}
```

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_input_seq % declare a list (seq) variable
\tl_new:N \l_last_word_tl % declare a "token list" variable
\NewDocumentCommand{\reverseit}{m}
  {
    \tl_if_blank:nF {#1} % If the input contains no words, do nothing.
      {
        % Split the argument into words (~ stands for a space here).
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_input_seq { ~ } {#1}
        % Remove the last word from the seq.
        \seq_pop_right:NN \l_input_seq \l_last_word_tl
        % Put the last word on the left of the sequence.
        \seq_put_left:NV \l_input_seq \l_last_word_tl
        % Use the contents of the sequence, separating words by a space (~).
        \seq_use:Nnnn \l_input_seq { ~ } { ~ } { ~ }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

```
\begin{document}

\reverseit{Hannes Alfv\'{e}n}

\reverseit{}

\reverseit{one}

\reverseit{one two}

\reverseit{one two three}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "easier to follow" than my code, how could that be possible? (+1 anyway:-)

Comment: May you add the option of placing a comma after the first item (after exchange), if it's not the unique one?

Comment: @egreg Something like `\seq_if_empty:NF \l_input_seq { \tl_put_right:Nn \l_last_word_tl { , } }` between the `pop` and `put lines would do it, I think.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, more adaptable, perhaps.

Comment: Joseph's approach should work.