# Extract the last word from a sentence stored in a variable

Tags: macros, programming, strings

I want to extract the last word of a sentence stored in a variable, e.g. `\thevariable`. Here is the minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Function to extract the last word of a sentence
\protected\def\TheLastWord#1{\xreverseit{}#1 \relax} 
\def\xreverseit#1#2 #3{%
\ifx\relax#3%
#2%
\expandafter\xthree
\fi
\xreverseit{#1 #2}#3}
\def\xthree#1#2#3{}

\newcommand\thevariable{The example sentence} % Store the sentence in a variable

\begin{document}

\TheLastWord{The example sentence} % Will print the last word 'sentence' -> CORRECT!

\TheLastWord{\thevariable} % Will just print the whole sentence: 'The example sentence' -> WRONG!

\end{document}
```

The code and the function`\TheLastWord` were picked up and modified from **David Carlisle**'s excellent work as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89304/how-to-make-the-last-word-in-a-sequence-the-first).

As you can see with the minimal example, it works for text input (`\TheLastWord{The example sentence}`) but is failed when the input is a variable (`\TheLastWord{\thevariable}`) storing the same sentence.

What is the reason for this failure? How to modify the code to make it work with the variable input?

Comment: `\expandafter\TheLastWord\expandafter{\thevariable}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When TeX finds

```
\TheLastWord{\thevariable}
```

it transforms it into

```
\xreverseit{}\thevariable•\relax
```

(the `•` denotes a space token). Now the first argument to `\xreverseit` is empty, the second is `\thevariable` and the third is `\relax`, so TeX does

```
\ifx\relax\relax\thevariable\expandafter\xthree\fi\xreverseit{•\thevariable}\relax
```

Since the test returns true, `\thevariable` remains in the input stream and it is expanded; then `\expandafter` gets rid of the `\fi` and the input stream will have

```
\xthree\xreverseit{•\thevariable}\relax
```

that expands to nothing, by the definition of `\xthree`.

---

The moral of the story is that you have to expand `\thevariable` before `\TheLastWord` (or, more precisely, `\xreverseit`) enters into action.

Either you use

```
\expandafter\TheLastWord\expandafter{\thevariable}
```

or you change the code

```
\documentclass{article}

% Function to extract the last word of a sentence
\newcommand*\TheLastWord[1]{\expandafter\xreverseit\expandafter{\expandafter}#1 \relax}
\def\xreverseit#1#2 #3{%
  \ifx\relax#3%
  #2%
  \expandafter\xthree
  \fi
  \xreverseit{#1 #2}#3% 
}
\def\xthree#1#2#3{}

\newcommand\thevariable{The example sentence} % Store the sentence in a variable

\begin{document}

\TheLastWord{The example sentence} 

\TheLastWord{\thevariable}

\end{document}
```

Of course this will also try expanding the first token when the sentence is given in explicit form.

I removed `\protected` in front of `\def\TheLastWord`: this macro is fully expandable, so there's no point in protecting it.

[image]