# Problem with theorem's numbering when using Arabi package

Tags: amsthm, arabic, persian

When I use a theorem style environment with Arabi package, the numbering become corrupted just after the numbers with two digits start.

Here an example. The number of the last one should be 10 but it shows 01.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE,OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[farsi,english,arabic]{babel}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exer}[thm]{تمرین}
\theoremstyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{farsi}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number is of printed backwards, so we want to reverse it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE,OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[farsi,english,arabic]{babel}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\revarabic}{m}
 {
  \tl_reverse:f { \arabic{#1} }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_reverse:n { f }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exer}[thm]{تمرین}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\renewcommand\thethm{\revarabic{thm}}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{farsi}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a version that doesn't use `expl3`; the macro is the same as in [this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36070/4427)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE,OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[farsi,english,arabic]{babel}

\makeatletter
\def\revarabic#1{%
  \expandafter\num@reverse\expandafter{\romannumeral-`Q\arabic{#1}}%
}
\def\num@reverse#1{\num@rev#1\num@rev@a\num@rev@b}
\def\num@rev#1#2\num@rev@a#3\num@rev@b{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {#1#3}%
  {\num@rev#2\num@rev@a#1#3\num@rev@b}%
}
\makeatother


\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exer}[thm]{تمرین}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\renewcommand\thethm{\revarabic{thm}}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{farsi}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\end{exer}
\begin{exer}\label{x}\end{exer}

\ref{x}
\end{document}
```

I added a `\label` to show the reference is correct.

Comment: when I compile the file I get the following error:      ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
l.13 \cs_generate_variant:Nn
                             \tl_reverse:n { f }

Comment: @Name You have an outdated TeX system. I'll add later a version independent on `expl3`, but you should upgrade your TeX distribution anyway.

Comment: I would be really grateful if you could provide a version independent form expl3.

Comment: @Name I added it and also fixed the `expl3` version.