# \pageref dosen't properly show the page number when using arabi package

Tags: cross-referencing, page-numbering, arabic, persian

In the page 10 of the following document I define a label. When I give a reference to the page number of this label in the following page, the number is not shown properly. The number appears as 01 instead of 10. Is there a way to solve this problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE,OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[farsi,english,arabic]{babel}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{farsi} 
$\ $
\newpage
$\ $
\newpage
$\ $
\newpage
$\ $
\newpage
$\ $
\newpage
$\ $
\newpage
$\ $
\newpage
$\ $
\newpage
$\ $
\newpage
$\ $
\label{page10}
\newpage
\pageref{page10}

\end{document}
```

Edited: This question is related to my previous question  
[Problem with theorem's numbering when using Arabi package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/205415/579)

In that situation the problem was solved by putting `\renewcommand\thethm{\revarabic{thm}}` after defining `\revarabic`. In the current situation I tried to mimicking the previous solution by putting the following without success

`\renewcommand\thepageref[1]{\revarabic{\pageref[#1]}}` (makes error)

`\renewcommand\pageref[1]{\revarabic{\pageref[#1]}}` (makes error)

`\renewcommand\thepage{\revarabic{page}}` (solves the problem with \pageref by but makes another inconvenience: now the number of the page 10 becomes 01)

Comment: looks like the same problem reported as [Problem with theorem's numbering when using Arabi package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/205415/579)

Comment: @barbarabeeton in the problem which you provided a link, egreg solved the problem by putting \renewcommand\thethm{\revarabic{thm}} after defining \revarabic. In this situation what I should put?

Comment: hmm.  i didn't realize that problem was also submitted by you.  unfortunately, applying that solution isn't quite as straightforward as i thought, although i'm sure the approach is in general the correct one.  i'll keep trying, although i hope that egreg will see this problem and respond.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the writing direction is always right-to-left when calling `\pageref`, this will do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE,OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,arabic,farsi]{babel}
\usepackage{xparse,etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% the following is from the other answer, not really needed here
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\revarabic}{m}
 {
  \tl_reverse:f { \arabic{#1} }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_reverse:n { f }

% the command needed here
\NewDocumentCommand{\reversed}{m}
 {
  \tl_reverse:n { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% patch \label so that it writes \thepage (expanded) as argument to \reversed
\patchcmd{\label}{\thepage}{\reversed{\thepage}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\pageref{page10}
% generate nine pages
\count255=0 \loop\ifnum\count255<9 \advance\count255 by 1 \null\newpage\repeat
% on the tenth put a label    
\null\label{page10}\newpage

\end{document}
```

I don't know `arabi`, but probably it has some switch that can enable the reversing of the argument only if the write direction is right-to-left.

Here's the version without `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE,OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,arabic,farsi]{babel}
\usepackage{xparse,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% the following is from the other answer, not really needed here
\def\revarabic#1{%
  \expandafter\num@reverse\expandafter{\romannumeral-`Q\arabic{#1}}%
}
% the command needed here
\protected\def\reversed#1{\num@reverse{#1}}

% the auxiliary commands
\def\num@reverse#1{\num@rev#1\num@rev@a\num@rev@b}
\def\num@rev#1#2\num@rev@a#3\num@rev@b{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {#1#3}%
  {\num@rev#2\num@rev@a#1#3\num@rev@b}%
}
\makeatother

% patch \label so that it writes \thepage (expanded) as argument to \reversed
\patchcmd{\label}{\thepage}{\reversed{\thepage}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\pageref{page10}
% generate nine pages
\count255=0 \loop\ifnum\count255<9 \advance\count255 by 1 \null\newpage\repeat
% on the tenth put a label    
\null\label{page10}\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I confirm that your solution perfectly works.