# How to change the shape of reference numbers in the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, formatting

I have the following document. After compiling the document, the reference number in the bibliography appears as [ 1 ]. I would like to know if it would be possible to do the following customizations without introducing any external package.

- [ 1 ] appears as [*1*], i.e., the reference number becomes italic.
- [ 1 ] appears as [**1**], i.e., the reference number becomes bold.
- [ 1 ] appears as [image], i.e., just the reference number (and not the brackets) becomes bigger.

Of course I can do these manually, i.e., by writing

```
\bibitem[\mbox{\it{1}}]{one}
\bibitem[\mbox{\bf{1}}]{one}
\bibitem[\mbox{\Large{1}}]{one}
```

But I would like to do them automatically, i.e., for all references.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a text.

\begin{thebibliography}{MM}
\bibitem{one}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Redefine `\@biblabel`:

To have the number boldfaced:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{[\textbf{#1}]}
\makeatother
```

To have the number in italics:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{[\textit{#1}]}
\makeatother
```

To increase the font size of the number:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{[{\Large#1}]}
\makeatother
```

A complete example with the number in italics:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{[\textit{#1}]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{MM}
\bibitem{one} Test one.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]