# How to change the shape of reference numbers in both bibliography (as boldface) and citations (as italic)

Tags: bibliographies, formatting

Using the answer provided in [How to change the shape of reference numbers in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/214573/3954), I have a document where the reference numbers in the bibliography are shown as boldface.

Now at the same time that this number is shown in boldface in the bibliography I would like that when citing that reference in the body of the text, the reference number appears as italic, i.e. `\cite{one}` writes the  number of the reference as italic (and not the [ ]'s), like [*1*].

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \makeatletter
    \def\@biblabel#1{[\textbf{#1}]}
    \makeatother
    \begin{document}

    See the reference \cite{one}.

    \begin{thebibliography}{MM}
    \bibitem{one}

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you really doing the bibliography by hand?

Comment: @Johannes_B if do not use bibtex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether this is a good idea. Why having two diffrent formats for one same object? On the other hand, having the number in italics but the brackets in normal round font looks unpleasing.

In any case, here's how you can do it: simply redefine `\@cite` (I also used italics for eventual anotations, but if that is not required, replace

```
\def\@cite#1#2{[\textit{#1\if@tempswa , #2\else\kern.15em\fi}]}
```

with

```
\def\@cite#1#2{[\textit{#1\if@tempswa} , #2\fi]}
```

The `\kern` comes from an attempt to get italic correction (see discussion in comments).

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{[\textbf{#1}]}
\def\@cite#1#2{[\textit{#1\if@tempswa , #2\else\kern.15em\fi}]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

See the reference~\cite{one}.

\begin{thebibliography}{MM}
\bibitem{one}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Ooh, that looks strange. Maybe the brackets should be italic too? Alltough, not touching any of this seems to be the best idea :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B I know, but the OP explicitly mentioned number=italics, brackets=normalfont.

Comment: Oh, you are right. But i can hardly look at the output.

Comment: `\itshape doesn't automatically add the italic correction at the end; you have to do that.  so: `\def\@cite#1#2{[{\itshape#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}\/]}` *should* work, but it doesn't.  will report a problem to latex-bugs.

Comment: @barbarabeeton You're right. Do you think that `\def\@cite#1#2{[\textit{#1\if@tempswa , #2\else\,\fi}]}` would be a better redefinition?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- well, it would behave uniformly.  certainly *something* is needed to space that out nicely.  try out the `\,` and also an ordinary `[{\itshape 1\/}]` to see if the spacing is close to the same; maybe a small `\kern .Nem` would be closer; don't know without trying.  and try a couple different numerals (although they're all the same width in cm, so the extra tests are only for confirmation).

Comment: @barbarabeeton After some tests, I added a kerning that seems reasonable. What do you think of it now?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- a *lot* nicer (after i clicked to see the edit).