# Problem with referencing to the the number of an equation when using arabic support of babel

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, babel, labels, arabic

Unfortunately, I have a problem when using babel with arabic. When deferring to the number of an equation, the digits are reversed. In the below document when using `(\ref{eq:10})` it gives `(01)` instead of `(10)`.

I have tried the following without success:
`\renewcommand\theequation{\revarabic{equation}}` where `revarabic` is provided by the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214613/.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE,OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[farsi,english,arabic]{babel}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{farsi} 

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:1}
  jhjh
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:2}
  hjh
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:3}
kjk  
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:4}
kjk  
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:5}
kjk  
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:6}
kjk  
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:7}
  jhjh
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:8}
  hjh
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:9}
kjk  
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:10}
kjk  
\end{equation}

\vspace{2cm}


{\selectlanguage{english} We now use the equation:}

(\ref{eq:10})

\end{document}
```

Comment: if you want indien-arabic digits use `(\I{\ref{eq:label}})` if you want arabic ones `(\textLR{\ref{eq:label}})`

Comment: You mean `\I{}\ref{eq:label}`? this does not solves the problem for me. You can do what you asking for by : `\let\arref\ref
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\I{\arref{#1}}}` then `\ref{eq:label}` will works fine

Comment: @touhami yes of course I meant `\I{ ...}`. I confirm that your comment solve the problem. I you like, please convert your comment to an answer, in order that I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In RL mode (arabic or farsi text) numbers should by coded using

- `\I{123}` to be typested in arabo-indic digits or extended arabo-indic digits.
- `\textLR{123}` to be typested in arabic digits.

Here we can use `(\I{\ref{eq:label}})`.

We can redefine `\ref` command like this

```
\let\arref\ref
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\I{\arref{#1}}}
```