# How right to left works in latex?

Tags: numbering, right-to-left

I tried to write Arabic numerals. For individual digits, there is no problem, but the problem starts with two numbers or more like the example below:

1980 should be ١٩٨٠ [correct]. But in my case I got ٠٨٩١ which means 0891 [Reversed, not correct] .

Comment: Nitpick: Technically they are all arabic numerals, right to left ones are eastern arabic numerals. Can you show us your document that doesn't give the right results?

Comment: @percusse There is no change in direction for numerals; apart from the shape of digits, numerals written in English and Arabic are exactly the same when looked at. Which is a problem when a number is generated and then printed in reverse form.

Comment: @egreg Yes. I meant the naming convention. The rest is plain MWE request.

Comment: may be duplicate, see the answer of this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252582/problem-with-referencing-to-the-the-number-of-an-equation-when-using-arabic-supp

Comment: @SoranAlnaqshbandi : Please provide a Minimal Working Example which replicates the problem, help us help you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same advice given by @touhami in a previous answer to a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252582/problem-with-referencing-to-the-the-number-of-an-equation-when-using-arabic-supp).

Since you didn't provide a MWE, I assumed you are using the `babel` package. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,arabic]{babel}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{Arabic}
بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم

نحن نستخدم الآن الجمل باللغة العربية : 

١٩٨٠

1980

\I{1980}

\I{١٩٨٠}

\bigskip

{
\selectlanguage{english} 
We are now using the English language sentence ...

1980 \par
\I{1980}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]